# Simulator flips to iPhone

Tags: iphone

I created my first universal app by using the universal app template.
I set up xib files and main view controllers for both iPhone and iPad and the iPhone version runs fine.

Yet even though I change the simulator hardware to iPad/3.2 when I test, the simulator changes back to the iPhone.

Please help.

Dan

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I change the targeted device in the project settings from iPhone/iPad to iPad, I can test.  I'll have to change it back when I'm ready to release the product.  Who knows if it will work.

Side issue: I found that the new imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation is not supported in 3.2.  I have to branch upon the interface idiom.